# $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\int_{0}^x e^{t^2}dt)^2 }{\int_{0}^{x} e^{2t^2}dt}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\int_{0}^x e^{t^2}dt)^2 }{\int_{0}^{x} e^{2t^2}dt}$$

My attempt: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\int_{0}^x e^{t^2}dt)^2 }{\int_{0}^{x} e^{2t^2}dt} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\int_{0}^x e^{t^2}dt) }{\int_{0}^{x} e^{2t^2}dt}\cdot\int_{0}^x e^{t^2}dt$$

Then we see that $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{(\int_{0}^x e^{t^2}dt) }{\int_{0}^{x} e^{2t^2}dt}$ can be solved using L'Hopitals and FTC

$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^{x^2}}{e^{2x^2}}=1$

Also $\lim_{x \to 0} \int_{0}^x e^{t^2}dt = 0$

Hence the answer is 0. Is this okay?

Comment: I don't know exactly what Leibniz rule has to do with this, but it's essentially correct.

Comment: And obviously you should always write $\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$.

Comment: Technically $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt\right)^2=\color{red}{2}e^{x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt$, but that factor of $\color{red}{2}$ doesn't stop you being right that the limit is $0$.

Comment: @J.G. I took $\int_{0}^x (e^{t^2}dt)^2 $ as two seperate terms so I got a term like $\int_{0}^x (e^{t^2}dt) \times \frac{ \int_{0}^x (e^{t^2}dt)}{\int_{0}^x (e^{2t^2}dt) } $ So if we apply limit we get $ 0 \times 1$

Comment: But $(u^2)'=2uu'$ by the product rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $x>0$ by Cauchy-Schwarz, $(\int_0^x 1)(\int_0^x e^{2t^2} dt) \ge (\int_0^x e^{t^2}dt)^2$

Thus $0\le \frac{(\int_0^x e^{t^2}dt)^2}{\int_0^x e^{2t^2} dt} \le x$ and we are done by squeeze theorem.

If $x<0$ by Cauchy-Schwarz, $(\int_x^0 1)(\int_x^0 e^{2t^2} dt) \ge (\int_x^0 e^{t^2}dt)^2$

Thus $0\le \frac{(\int_x^0 e^{t^2}dt)^2}{\int_x^0 e^{2t^2} dt} \le -x$ so  $\frac{(\int_0^x e^{t^2}dt)^2}{\int_0^x e^{2t^2} dt} \in (x,0)$. We are done by squeeze theorem.

Comment: That's for $x>0$.

Comment: Good point, but should be easily fixable.

Answer (score 3):

Bare handed solution:
$$\left (\int\limits_0^xe^{t^2}\,dt\right )^2\le (xe^{x^2})^2=x^2e^{2x^2}$$
$$\int\limits_0^xe^{2t^2}\,dt\ge \int\limits_{0}^x \,dt\ge x$$ The ratio is bounded above by $$xe^{2x^2}$$ The integrated functions are even, so the conclusion (not the proof) holds for $x<0.$

**Remark** The limit at $\infty$ is slightly more challenging.

Comment: is my attempt also correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.